# Sort specific range of data frame by a column in R

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, range

I have a data.frame of size 8326x13. I would like to order it in parts by a specific column. E.g. order the range 1:1375 only by the column A. Then, I would like to add this order part to same data.frame into the correct place 1:1375. Is it possible?

Thanks in advanced.

Raúl.

Comment: split it into separate data frames sort them how you want then rbind them back into a single data frame

Comment: Or use `ddply` which does exactly that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or, (using the dataset of `useR`)

```
 indx <- rep(c(TRUE,FALSE), each=10) #create a logical index.
```

In this case the first 10 rows are ordered

```
 data[indx,] <- data[order(data$A[indx]),]
```

#### Update

Or instead of creating a logical `index`, extract the rows that needs to be ordered and replace it with the ordered set

```
 data[1:10,] <- data[order(data$A[1:10]),]
```

In your dataset if you create a index,

```
  indx <- rep(c(TRUE,FALSE), c(1375, 8326-1375))
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @JeremyS

```
A <- sample(1:100, 20)
B <- sample(letters[1:26],20)
data <- data.frame(A, B)

n <- 10                                      # you want range 1:n
lower <- data[(n+1):dim(data)[1], ]          # split to two data.frame with lower and upper part
upper <- data[1:n,]  
upper <- upper[order(upper$A),]              # or order(upper[,m]), m is the column index

data.new <- rbind.data.frame(upper, lower)
```